# How to change default settings on installation disk?

Tags: lubuntu, settings, default

I am wanting to install Lubuntu on a bunch of computers and laptops. I would rather not through each individual installation and change the settings to how I want them. Is there a way to set the settings prior to installation on the installation disk (which is a USB)?

Comment: I think what you need is described here: https://askubuntu.com/a/827074/763460

Comment: You can build a custom iso. This is outlined in the official Ubuntu help docs. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: Sorry, I originally posted the wrong URL for the help documentation. The link has been edited and should now be correct. Again, here is the link to the documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization